# Is there a way to determine a visitors country from the client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geocoding

I'm using google maps and the geocoding API to retrieve a users lat/lng after they enter a zip/postal code but I want to limit the zip/postal codes to that users country so I don't end up with multiple results.

Is there a way to reliably determine a visitors country of origin from the client maybe using jquery or possible decoding the user agent somehow?

My call would end of looking something like this:

```
var country = ???
var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value + ', ' + country;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();         
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postcode }, function (results, status) {          
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  
       ...
   }
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mry4/)

Comment: @adeneo That's perfect! I'll check out the API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of not relying on a third-party, you can get the client's location by using [Google's Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader). [Here's a great example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940767/how-to-get-client-location-using-google-maps-api-v3) of this in use, loading the Google Maps API and ClientLocation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the visitors IP address to look up his origin in a GeoIP Table.
There are various tables around, e.g. [from MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/opensource).

Note that this might fail if the user is behind a proxy server or you are unable to obtain the IP. Apart from that it should be a quite reliable method, depending on your GeoIP table of course.